# using arraylist in struts

Tags: struts

I have a group of text fields by year wise like present year,previous year,next year in jsp. i need to take that values and pass the values by action classs and display in the another JSP can any one tell me how to do and give me the example code.

the text box is like below senario

```
field name      Previous year   current year    next year
----------  -------------   ------------    ----------
A       textbox     textbox     textbox
B       textbox     textbox     textbox
C       textbox     textbox     textbox
.         .        .           .
.         .        .           .
.         .        .           .
.         .        .           .
```

Comment: what have you done so far? and where you facing issue? it better to show the code part

Comment: Actually i didnt done anything i have an scenario may be i can use like this